# How can we control particular key should go in a specific reducer?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

How can we control particular key should go in a specific reducer? Can someone help me with this question?

Comment: I think you can do this by using custom partitioner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [partitioner](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Partitioner.html) is main mechanism to control which keys get sent to a specific reducer.

> Partitioner controls the partitioning of the keys of the intermediate
>   map-outputs. The key (or a subset of the key) is used to derive the
>   partition, typically by a hash function. The total number of
>   partitions is the same as the number of reduce tasks for the job.
>   Hence this controls which of the m reduce tasks the intermediate key
>   (and hence the record) is sent for reduction.

The default partitioner is the [HashPartitoner](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/partition/HashPartitioner.html), which uses the `hashCode()` of the key object to determine which reduce a given key is sent to.

In your driver you can set a different partitioner using:

```
job.setPartitionerClass(Class<? extends Partitioner> cls)
```

Custom partitioners implement the `Partitioner<K2, V2>` interface which has a single method `getPartition(KEY key, VALUE value, int numPartitions)` that needs implementing.

For example the `HashPartitioner` implementation of `getPartition` looks like:

```
public int getPartition(K2 key, V2 value,int numReduceTasks) {
  return (key.hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % numReduceTasks;
}
```